# Django thousands and decimal separation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the following code as my filters:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

register = template.Library()


def euro_amount(euro):
    euro=round(float(euro),2)
    return "€%s%s" % (intcomma(int(euro)), ("%0.2f" % euro)[-3:])

register.filter('euro_amount', euro_amount)
```

But it shows me ad example 1.000.00 €, but I wanto to obtain the following result: 1.000,00 €.

How can I obtain it?

Comment: Normally that depends on the locale of the user. So a German user will se `1.000,00` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom filter to replace the first `,` with `.`. In the file where you have your custom filters and tags, add following function

```
 from django import template
 register = template.Library()

 @register.filter
 def replace_commas(str):
    return str.replace(',', '.',1) #replaces the fist instance only
```

Comment: mmm okey but I don't have custom filters or tags file. How  does it work?

Comment: It simply filters out what you want to render. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/). And a good walkthrough [here](http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html)

Comment: I have updated my question on base your considerations. Could merge my code with yours? With replace statement

Comment: @Jfix91 yes use the `replace()` method. This should do exactly what you want.